# Ask for generic password before showing hidden div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have a hidden div be shown once someone enters in a password. The password isn't looking at a database. It can be something like testpass for now. Here's my coding so far. It can be in anything java, javascript or something else. We use Coldfusion. I'm guessing javascript would be the easiest, but I'm not sure. What do I need to add in order to enter in testpass to show what's hidden? Security doesn't matter. I just want the user to enter in something before it shows them what's hidden.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
                        
    <style>
        .buttongrt {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


</style>

</head>

<body>
<button onclick="hideform()" class="buttongrt">show form</button>

<div id="buttonfgc" style="display:none">
thing that it's hiding</div>
    <br>thing that it's not hiding
    <script type="text/javascript">
function hideform() {
    var T = document.getElementById("buttonfgc"),
        displayValue = "";
    if (T.style.display == "")
        displayValue = "none";

    T.style.display = displayValue;
}
            </script>
        </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This really leans more into a matter of design. Do you already have some sort of authentication/user-level perms setup? You could just have a cfif statement wrapping the div to show, or as a condition to code that sets the tag.

Just have it do a call to a Service that returns the user perm level, and check against that.

Comment: Not really a permission issue. It's the receivers like to hit a button that's in a form and it will receive everything. I would like it to make them type something in so they're aware of what they're doing.